# Why is this giving Exception in 'main' java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException`. That's all, can anyone figure out why?

```
class one{
    String name;
}

class oneTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        one[] obj = new one[2];

        obj[0].name = "IBM";
        obj[1].name = "AGM";

        System.out.println(obj[0].name);
        System.out.println(obj[1].name);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
one[] obj = new one[2];
```

This creates room for two `one` objects, but it doesn't actually create them!

Do it like this:

```
one[] obj = new one[2];
obj[0] = new one();
obj[1] = new one();
obj[0].name = "IBM";
obj[1].name = "AGM";
```

Btw, according to Java Language naming conventions, the class `one` should be in upper case.

And while we're at it, I'd give your `One` class a constructor:

```
class One{
    String name;

    public One(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And now you can create the whole array in one line:

```
One[] obj = new One[]{new One("IBM"),new One("AGM")};
```

(next I'd make the `name` field private and add a getter method, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `new` to create `one` instances.  Right now your array does not contain any instances, but you are trying to set the `name` property on instance.  When you do

`obj[0].name`

`obj[0]` is null, and you can't get a property on  null....

Try something like...

```
one one1 = new one();
one1.name = "IBM"
obj[0] = one1;
```

BTW, class names in java should be properly camel cased....

Comment: Complementing your answer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
one[] obj = new one[2];
```

you create an array with two elements, but these elements are references not objects of type `one`. You never actually create any instances of `one` at all. You can do it like this:

```
obj[0] = new one();
```

Only once you create these instances, can you assign values to their fields as you do here:

```
obj[0].name = "IBM";
```

Before you assign any reference to `obj[0]` it is equal to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
one[] obj = new one[2];
```

Above statement just creates type of One[] with size 2, but it doesnt contain any One object

First you need to create object for that location, then only you can set name.

```
   One temp = new One();
temp.name = "IBM";
        obj[0] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

When an array of objects is created in Java, each element is initialized to null. You must initialize each element yourself.
Ex:

```
one[] obj = new one[2];
for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
  obj[i] = new one();
}
```